# React-native-popover is showing error.Not only this when I am using the asserts images it is giving the same error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

**React-native-popover is showing error I found that inside node-module I found gif images are there and also StyleSheetRegistry module not found. Not only this when I am using the asserts images it is giving the same error if I am using the browser link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptYtw.png) images it is working fine. Could any one suggest me how to fix this issue.**

> SyntaxError: /home/user/Desktop/stackSideMenu/node_modules/react-native-popover/Screenshots/basic.png: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
>
> > 1 | �PNG
> >         | ^
> >       2 | 
> >       3 | 
> >       4 | IHDR@Ԍ�DgAMA��
> >                               �a cHRMz&�����u0�`:�p��Q< pHYs                                                                                                                        ��YiTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp
> >         at Parser.pp.raise (/home/user/Desktop/stackSideMenu/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:22:13)
> >         at Parser.getTokenFromCode (/home/user/Desktop/stackSideMenu/node_modules/babylon/lib/tokenizer/index.js:561:12)
> >         at Parser.readToken (/home/user/Desktop/stackSideMenu/node_modules/babylon/lib/tokenizer/index.js:180:21)
> >         at Parser. (/home/user/Desktop/stackSideMenu/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:51:20)
> >         at Parser.readToken (/home/user/Desktop/stackSideMenu/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/flow.js:170:22)
> >         at Parser.nextToken (/home/user/Desktop/stackSideMenu/node_modules/babylon/lib/tokenizer/index.js:169:21)
> >         at Parser.parse (/home/user/Desktop/stackSideMenu/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/index.js:128:12)
> >         at parse (/home/user/Desktop/stackSideMenu/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:47:47)
> >         at File.parse (/home/user/Desktop/stackSideMenu/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:517:34)
> >         at File.parseCode (/home/user/Desktop/stackSideMenu/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:603:20)

Comment: I see error from time to time, I'm not sure what causes it, but restarting the server always fixes it. Have you tried restarting?

Comment: yes I tried But it is giving same error message.

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe try different image files, maybe that one's been corrupted. It would probably help, if you could provide more info. Add some code to your question. Show the code that worked, and the code the failed.

Comment: @Kyle Finley you are right restarting the server. It is working fine now.